Does the slope of the line through these curves necessarily have nonzero derivative?

I have two curves $\gamma_1(u),\gamma_2(v) : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, which are well-behaved --- smooth, bounded, and locally invertible. They have the property that every line which crosses both curves intersects them a finite number of times. (Call this the Finite intersection property.)

Evidently, any line which crosses both curves can be specified by giving two points $\gamma_1(u), \gamma_2(v)$ where the crossings occur, or equivalently by giving the values $u$ and $v$.

Alternatively, the lines can be specified by their slope $A(u,v)$ and y-intercept $B(u,v)$.

I want to prove that because of the Finite intersection property, generally speaking changing the value of $u$ or $v$ must change the line joining their points. When I attempt to formalize this, I want to claim that the partials of $A$ and $B$ must be nowhere zero --- but I can imagine edge cases, I think, where one of these partials vanishes at isolated points but the Finite intersection property is still satisfied --- so maybe I need a weaker property.

My question is:



Does the finite intersection property for these smooth curves force the partials of $A$ and $B$ to be everywhere nonzero (except possibly at a finite set of points?)

I've attempted to prove this with the implicit function theorem and the determinant formula for determining whether three points are collinear, but have not had much luck. I suspect I am missing some additional tool or insight.

The lines could be vertical (no?), in which case you should tell us what you want $A(u, v)$ to be ($\infty$? $-\infty$? And what notion of differentiability do you have in mind then?).

Yes; let's ignore that case. We can consider just where A and B are well-defined.
